# My server won't accept files larger then 2MB?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I already Check with the settings in php.ini, Every thing is fine. Any other i have to change to make it works?

Comment: what error showing ?

Comment: Is it in phpmyadmin or php side problem?

Comment: `ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');`

Comment: change  "upload_max_filesize" in php.ini

Comment: set in php.in ` post_max_size = 20M`.

Comment: change post_max_size = 'how much you want to give' and  upload_max_filesize = 'same as given above' in php.ini. And don't forget to restart your xampp/wampp server. Otherwise changes not works.

Comment: This is Strange, i couldn't figure what error is it. I already set ini_set('post_max_size', '20M'); and ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M'); Both are  20M now.Still its not happening Any other things i have to check?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 10M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 10M
```

After modifying php.ini file, you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

Comment: This is Strange, i couldn't figure what error is it. I already set ini_set('post_max_size', '20M'); and ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M'); Both are 20M now. Any other things i have to check?

Comment: Do you have access to `php.ini` file ?

Comment: Yes, i checked in apache's php.ini and also in cli php.ini

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php 
upload_max_filesize "2M" PHP_INI_PERDIR  
http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php
 
PHP_INI_PERDIR Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)
 
So you can't use ini_set for this.